# How to send the list item ID in email (when item is created)

Tags: id, send-email

I am trying to create a workflow that runs when a new item is created.  Basically, I want to send an email notification that includes the ID value (of the list item) when a new list item is saved/submitted.  However, the workflow works and an email will be sent but ID field value from body of email is blank...although when I go back to the lists, value has already been assigned to ID field.

Can somebody assists me on how the workflow be setup to have the ID field get its value, before the "send email" action in the workflow get triggered?  so that when email is sent out it will show the ID field value assigned to the list item.

[image: Workflow]

And the email sample is below;

[image: Email sample]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your workflow on `On item creating` event? if yes then change it to `on item created` event, after that, you can able to get the list item ID. Still, if you are not able to get the item ID then add "pause until" action of some seconds and place that action before send email action in `On item created` event.

Comment: The Pause until action seems to fix my issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

List Item ID is generated immediately after you creates item in list. Try setting your `UniqueNo` variable before `IF Statement`.

Check below image for reference:

[image]